# Select associated element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-selectors

I have a text-area where each sentence has a separate text-piece (an argument) associated. By default, all the arguments are hidden, but I want jQuery to enable a toggle-function, so that when a user clicks on a sentence, the corresponding argument becomes visible beneath the entire text-area.

However, I can't figure out how to only show the one specific argument instead of all the arguments (which is what my code does now, I know). So, how do I select the argument associated with the clicked sentence?

My code looks like this:

```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.arg-sentence').click(function() {
               $('.argument').slideToggle('slow'); <-- This should only select one specific argument
          });
     });
  </script>

  {% block content %}

  <div class="text">
  {% for arg in catalog %}
  <span class="arg-sentence" id="{{ arg.id }}">{{ arg.sentence }}</span>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
  {% block content-secondary %}

  {% for arg in catalog %}
  <div class="col-sm-12 content_holder well argument" id="{{ arg.id}}">
      <div class="text">
          {{ arg.argument|safe }}
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endblock %}
```

I'm new to jQuery so it might be something very obvious..! I'm using Django by the way..

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that did just what I wanted:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.arg-sentence').click(function() {
           $('#' + this.id + '.argument').slideToggle('slow'); 
      });
 });
</script>
```